# Spark writing performance csv vs snappy-orc

Tags: apache-spark, orc

If I need to write dataframe on disk which format will perform better csv or 'orc with snappy' ?

One hand csv format will avoid compression task overhead  but on another hand snappy will reduce total byte size writing task. Please correct me in assumptions here as well?

Note that my question is about writing performance not the storage point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Compression is about saving space, not performance, so the fact you're using Snappy is not really a relevant detail as you could use LZ4 or ZSTD instead, for example.

[ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) is a column oriented data format that performs better for analytics than CSV, and under certain conditions, will outperform Spark's default format of Parquet.

Comment: Thanks for response. My question is to compare only for "writing performance". I understand advantages of orc in other aspect.

Comment: What are those outperform parquet conditions?

Comment: @theblue Columnar access and statistics gathering is likely to be faster for orc, but if just counting records or scanning all columns, it's expected to be about the same, yeah?

Comment: @Rex I'm not sure what you mean. The performance of writing files is measured by your hardware and network speeds, not by file types

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I am your side on this that file type may not be a factor. but what about file size impact bcz of compression as buffer writing will be reduced. Eg - one csv file of 10 MB size to write - if compressed size is 2 MB then wouldn't be a faster write because of byte array size and less network use ? where as if I am writing csv diect then I have to write 10 MB ? while evaluating need to adjust compute required in compression while deciding the winner.

Comment: @Rex Sure, there's less network use, but there's also higher cpu use by compressing, so it's a tradeoff. It would also need decompressed whenever queried. Since Orc can also be snappy compressed, I still standby my point that file type doesn't matter